# Zurb Foundation for E-Mails: Outlook error on Images and <hr>

Tags: css, email, outlook, zurb-foundation

I have an bigger Image in a column-set of large 4. It is scaling down in most of the E-Mail Clients except Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013 & 2016 Windows.

In addition to that, I styled a nice hr-Divider – its color and weight is also ignored by those clients.

Here how it looks like:
[Screenshot](http://fet.moewe-cg.de/screenshot.png)

Here how it should look like:
[E-Mail](http://fet.moewe-cg.de/OutlookProblem.html)

Here is the html-code written in inky:

```
<row class="logo">
  <columns small="6" large="4">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://assets.techdata-marketing.de/_template/newsletter/v1.0.0/img/tdnl_logo_tech-data_x2.jpg" alt="Logo">
    </a>
  </columns>
  <columns small="6" large="8"></columns>
</row>
```

SCSS:

```
.logo {
  .columns {
      padding-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess how to offer help? Please post your HTML code so we can see the issue.

Comment: I updated the code.